# Keyboard viewer in macOS Mojave dark mode

Tags: keyboard, graphics, mojave, ui, character-map

I upgraded to macOS Mojave and switched to dark mode.

I use **Accessibility Keyboard**. I am wondering if the keys on it are supposed to look like this in Light mode.

[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of your Mac? Are you using a MacBook Air?

Comment: @NimeshNeema MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know if they're **supposed** to, but they do, & have done since the first beta. Still the same in the latest beta 10.14.2

[image]

Sorry, some confusion... the picture in the OP isn't the Accessibility keyboard, it's the "Show Keyboard Viewer" keyboard, which used to be white & is now as above.

From High Sierra

[image]

The Accessibility keyboard seems to have been the same since High Sierra [can't test Sierra] & didn't exist in El Capitan.

[image]